# Google API Python client error

Tags: python, api, oauth-2.0, google-api-python-client

I want to have a script for getting home feed of Google+. I use for that google's  [script](https://github.com/musicmetric/google-api-python-client/blob/master/samples/plus/plus.py). The client-secrets.json file is:

```
{
 "web": {
   "client_id": "##########",
   "client_secret": "############",
   "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost:8080/oauth2callback/"],
   "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
   "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
   "client_email":"##########@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
   "javascript_origins":["http://localhost:8080/"]
        }
}
```

But when i want to start this app, it opens a page with error and broken robot:

`The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8080/ did not match a registered redirect URI`

Please, help me with my problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution! You should create another Client ID, but for desktop application! After that you need to use it's **client_id** and **client_secret**. It works for developing without hosting.

Comment: You make my evening. I spent 2 hours until found this answer, google needs to hire other guys to write documentation for them.

Answer (score 1):

The values you have used for `client_id` and `client_secret` correspond to a Google APIs Project that you have created and will access via

https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:XYZ

where `XYZ` is your project ID.

In this project, you'll need to make sure that `http://localhost:8080/` is a redirect URI by

1. Clicking the "APIs Access" tab on the right
2. Finding the corresponding "Client ID for web applications" box for your app
3. Clicking "Edit settings..."
4. Adding `http://localhost:8080/` to the "Authorized Redirect URIs" box

Comment: `The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:8080/ did not match a registered redirect URI`

Answer (score 0):

Running local server on **port 80** and making config URLs simply `http://localhost` fixed it for me.

e.g. for your case

```
{
 "web": {
   "client_id": "##########",
   "client_secret": "############",
   "redirect_uris": ["http://localhost/oauth2callback/"],
   "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
   "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
   "client_email":"##########@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
   "javascript_origins":["http://localhost"]
        }
}
```